# Absolute Values in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, absolute

I am new in SSRS reports and want to develop report in below mention format.
I want to get absolute values and then add.

i use the following query in dataset.

(Select S.Zone,S.City,H.EmpID,H.EmpName,H.Department,H.Designation,H.EmpDOL,H.JobLoc,Count(H.EmpID) as TotalStrength,0 as AvaStregth from HRData H
Left Join StoreTable S on H.JobLoc=S.StoreName
Group by S.ZOne,S.City,H.EmpID,H.EmpName,H.Department,H.Designation,H.EmpDOL,H.JobLoc

UNION ALL

Select S.Zone,S.City,NULL as City,NULL as EmpID,NULL as EmpName,T.Designation,NULL as EmpDOL,T.[Store Name],0,T.Value From HRTotalStrength T
Left Join StoreTable S on T.[Store Name]=S.StoreName)

[Fomat in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9dA9.png)

Comment: From your spreadsheet it seems you want to take the absolute value of the difference between TotalStrength and AvaStregth. Can you confirm that is what you want? The name of the absolute function in reporting services is called Abs. If you need help with expressions this would be a good place to start https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expressions-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You just need to use a table, group by store and add a total to each group, then add a total to your entire table. I suggest you read about some pf the SSRS basics. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/lesson-6-adding-grouping-and-totals-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15